# How to merge Constants inside a URL So it won't break the url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants

I have a URL as

`"http://localhost:8000/api/branding/news/";`

I want, domain Part to put inside a Constant like

`export const DOMAIN = "http://localhost:8000/";`

Now I'm adding this constant inside the URL

`{ DOMAIN } + "api/branding/news/";`

but, this isn't working... how to fix this?

Comment: leave the brackets around the Domain, then will works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use DOMAIN like this:

```
DOMAIN + "api/branding/news/"
```

But even better you can use template string:

```
`${DOMAIN}api/branding/news/`
```

Comment: don't forget to add a '/' between your variable and the path like `${DOMAIN}/api/brading/news/`
````

Comment: in  "export const DOMAIN = "http://localhost:8000 / "; already have a "/"